# What is the joint CDF of $f(x,y)=2(x+y), 0\leq x\leq y\leq 1$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

I am trying to find the joint CDF of $f(x,y)=2(x+y) : 0\leq x\leq y\leq 1$.

There are five different answers for the CDF depending on the restrictions of $x$ and $y$ that you use. I

found the CDF $F(x,y)=y^2x+x^2y-x^3\mbox{ if }0\leq x\leq y\leq 1$ and also I found the CDF $F(x,y)=0\mbox{ if }x<0 \land y<0$.

Now I need to find the CDF if $x>y$ and $0>y>1$ and then if $y>1$ and $0<x<1$. and for $y>1$ and $x>1$. I know how to do the integral and everything I am just unsure of what my bounds for each of these three integrals where we use double integrals would be.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like :

$$\begin{align}F(x,y) ~&=~ \begin{cases}
0 & : x<0 \lor y< 0
\\[4pt] \int_0^y\int_0^{\min(x,t)} f(s,t)\operatorname d s\operatorname d t & : 0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1
\\[4pt] \int_0^1 \int_0^{\min(x,t)} f(s,t)\operatorname d s\operatorname d t & : 0\leq x\leq 1, y> 1
\\[4pt] \int_0^y \int_0^t f(s,t)\operatorname d s\operatorname d t & : 0\leq y\leq 1, x> y
\\[4pt] 1 & : x> 1 \land y>1
\end{cases}
\\[2ex] &=~\begin{cases}
0 & : x<0 \lor y< 0
\\[4pt] \int_0^x\int_0^t 2(s+t)\operatorname d s\operatorname d t+
 \int_x^y\int_0^x 2(s+t)\operatorname d s\operatorname d t & : 0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1
\\[4pt] \int_0^x\int_0^t2(s+t)\operatorname d s\operatorname d t+
\int_x^1 \int_0^x 2(s+t)\operatorname d s\operatorname d t & : 0\leq x\leq 1, y> 1
\\[4pt] \int_0^y \int_0^t 2(s+t)\operatorname d s\operatorname d t & : 0\leq y\leq 1, x> y
\\[4pt] 1 & : x> 1 \land y>1
\end{cases}
\\[2ex] &=~\begin{cases}
0 & : x<0 \lor y< 0
\\[4pt] x y^2+ x^2 y -x^3 & : 0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1
\\[4pt] x + x^2 -x^3 & : 0\leq x\leq 1, y> 1
\\[4pt] y^3 & : 0\leq y\leq 1, x> y
\\[4pt] 1 & : x> 1 \land y>1
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

Comment: for the fourth one I happen to know the answer is y^3 so those bounds do not work for that.

Comment: same with the third one. The answer is x+x^2-x^3 and I am getting just x+x^2 with those bounds @GrahamKemp

Comment: @Graham Kemp What do you mean by min(x,t)?

Comment: The minimum of $x$ and $t$.