# Finding bounds for integration of joint pdf

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be continuous random variables with a joint pdf of the form $f(x,y) = 2(x+y)$ with $0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1$. Find the joint CDF, $F(x,y)$.

I know that I integrate $2(x+y)$, but do not understand how to get the bounds for integration.

Comment: Very similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1702269/deriving-joint-cdf-for-two-random-variables-x-and-y-from-joint-pdf

Comment: @Winther Do you know what min(2,y) and min(x,y,t) means?

Comment: The minimum-value of whats inside the brackets so for example $\min(2,3) = 2$ and $\min(2,1) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

We wish to integrate $\iint_{0\leqslant s\leqslant t\leqslant 1, s\leqslant x, t\leqslant y} 2(s+t)\operatorname d s\operatorname d t$ for various fixed values of $x,y$.

[$$F_{X,Y}(x,y)~=~\int_0^{\min\{y,1\}}\int_0^{\min\{x,t,y\}} 2(s+t)\operatorname d s\operatorname d t$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010170/what-is-the-joint-cdf-of-fx-y-2xy-0-x-y-1/1010220?noredirect=1#comment4528962_1010220)

---

The support $\{(s,t):0\leqslant s\leqslant t\leqslant 1\}$ is the right triangle in the unit square above-and-left of the diagonal through the origin; that is $\triangle(0,0)(0,1)(1,1)$.

You will be interested in integrating over $\{(s,t):0\leqslant s\leqslant t\leqslant 1, s\leqslant x, t\leqslant y\}$ and the point $(x,y)$ exists in the following five regions:

- $x<0~\vee~y<0$, that is to the left or below the unit square.
  $$\{(s,t):0\leqslant s\leqslant x < 0~\vee~0\leqslant t\leqslant y\leqslant 0\}=\{\}$$
- $0\leqslant x\leqslant y\leqslant 1$, that is inside the triangle.
  $$\{(s,t): 0\leqslant s\leqslant x\leqslant y\leqslant 1, 0\leqslant s\leqslant t\leqslant y\}$$
- $0\leqslant x\leqslant 1, y>1$, that is above the triangle.
  $$\{(s,t): 0\leqslant s\leqslant x\leqslant 1, 0\leqslant s\leqslant t\leqslant 1, y>1\}\}$$
- $x>y, 0\leqslant y\leqslant 1$, that is right of the triangle.
  $$\{(s,t): 0\leqslant s\leqslant t\leqslant y\leqslant 1, x>y\}\}$$
- $x>1, y>1$, that is both above and right of the triangle. 
  $$\{(s,t): 0\leqslant s\leqslant t\leqslant 1, x>1, y>1 \}$$